# How to use update from select in hql?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, nhibernate, hql

I tried this:

```
    using (var s = HibernateSessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
        s.CreateQuery(
            @"UPDATE Guild as gg SET gg.PersistentXPSum = el.XPSum 
              WHERE gg.Id=el.GuildId FROM 
                (SELECT SUM(XP) AS XPSum, GuildId FROM User 
                     WHERE GuildId != null GROUP BY GuildId 
                     ORDER BY XPSum desc LIMIT 50) el").ExecuteUpdate();
```

But it gives `Antlr.Runtime.MismatchedTokenException` at line 2, column 41.

How to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented here

[13.3. DML-style operations](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct)

> ...
>   The pseudo-syntax for UPDATE and DELETE statements is: ( UPDATE | DELETE ) FROM? EntityName (WHERE where_conditions)?. Some points to note:
>
> - ...
> - No joins (either implicit or explicit) can be specified in a bulk HQL query. **Sub-queries may be used in the where-clause; the subqueries, themselves, may contain joins**.

So, we know, that we can use SUBQUERY. But that does **not** mean this syntax *(see the valid syntax below)*:

```
... = el.GuildId  FROM (SELECT ...) el")`
```

And also, very important note. There is **NO way**, how to specify the LIMIT in the inner HQL (sub)query. So, let's pretend we know the `50th` value: e.g. 1000.

The working query would be like:

```
s.CreateQuery(
    @"UPDATE Guild as gg 
      SET gg.PersistentXPSum = el.XPSum 
      WHERE gg.Id IN
        (SELECT GuildId FROM User 
             WHERE GuildId != null 
             GROUP BY GuildId 
             HAVING SUM(XP) > 1000) el")
 .ExecuteUpdate();
```

*NOTE: this is for sure working with SQL Server. Maybe there should be some adjsutment for postgresql... but not so crucial...*

Answer (score -1):

You can try below query :

```
s.createQuery("UPDATE Guild as gg SET gg.PersistentXPSum = el.XPSum WHERE gg.Id in (SELECT el.GuildId FROM (SELECT SUM(XP) AS XPSum, GuildId FROM User WHERE GuildId != null GROUP BY GuildId ORDER BY XPSum desc LIMIT 50) el)").executeUpdate();
```

Comment: the same exception, the position after `FROM`